# What are HTTP Status codes for informational and Server Error in multiple scenarios?

Tags: rest, http, networking, web

These are the Status Codes for HTTP in different cases.

```
1xx Informational 
2xx Success 
3xx Redirection 
4xx Client Error 
5xx Server Error
```

In which HTTP calls and scenarios user should report informational ? Also what should be code value? How are these code value should be decided?

In which HTTP calls and scenarios user should report server error? Also what should be code value? I have seen many places user get 500 or 504. What is the right value for it? Also can user return any other server error code? How are these code value should be decided?

Comment: Hint: Use Google:
https://httpstatuses.com

Comment: A server can return whatever status he finds applicable. However it makes sense to obey certain standard usages, so that the reply can actually be interpreted correctly. For most http status codes the usage is obvious, so what is your question here? If your server internally struggles that typically results in some 5xx code, if an error is raised die to a request that leads to a faulty state you will return a 4xx code. And likewise.Certainly your server could also return some status like 643020573, but that is not defined and no one will be able to make any sense from that, right?

Comment: Big thanks @peakpeak. That's the exact information I was looking for.   httpstatuses.com has quiet good information with details about each status code. Awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Informational** status codes (`1xx`) indicate an interim response for communicating connection status or request progress prior to completing the requested action and sending a final response.

**Server error** status codes (`5xx`) indicate that the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the requested method.

---

Use the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) as reference. It's the document that defines the semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol. See the details below.

### Informational status codes

> [**6.2.  Informational 1xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2)
>
> The `1xx` (Informational) class of status code indicates an interim
> response for communicating connection status or request progress
> prior to completing the requested action and sending a final
> response. `1xx` responses are terminated by the first empty line after
> the status-line (the empty line signaling the end of the header
> section).  Since HTTP/1.0 did not define any `1xx` status codes, a
> server MUST NOT send a `1xx` response to an HTTP/1.0 client.
>
> A client MUST be able to parse one or more 1xx responses received
> prior to a final response, even if the client does not expect one.  A
> user agent MAY ignore unexpected `1xx` responses.
>
> A proxy MUST forward `1xx` responses unless the proxy itself requested
> the generation of the `1xx` response.  For example, if a proxy adds an
> `Expect: 100-continue` field when it forwards a request, then it need
> not forward the corresponding `100` (Continue) response(s).

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) defines the following informational status codes:

- [`100`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2.1) Continue
- [`101`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2.2) Switching Protocols

### Server error status codes

> [**6.6.  Server Error 5xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6)
>
> The `5xx` (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server
> is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the
> requested method.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  A user agent SHOULD display any included representation
> to the user.  These response codes are applicable to any request
> method.

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) defines the following server error status codes:

- [`500`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) Internal Server Error
- [`501`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.2) Not Implemented
- [`502`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.3) Bad Gateway
- [`503`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) Service Unavailable
- [`504`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.5) Gateway Timeout
- [`505`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.6) HTTP Version Not Supported

---

All registered status codes and their official documentation can be seen [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml#http-status-codes-1).

To help you determine the most suitable status code, consider these [flowcharts](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code).

Comment: Thanks @Cassio for providing a quiet comprehensive details about the STATUS code for HTTP. Very useful info. Flowcharts are really good to decide the status code.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted